# Draw points in graph: what is the procedure called

Tags: c#, nodes, graph-theory, game-development

[draw a 2d Floorplan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VDc6.png)

I have been researching about this for the past few weeks, My end goal is to generate 3D floorplan by drawing a 2D floorplan.

I narrowed down my problem solving into figuring out how you can draw a 2D Floor p[demo link](http://furnishup.github.io/blueprint3d/example/#), I came across of Graph Theory and kind of get the idea. Now I wanted to create an interactable Graph where you draw points in the space and connect nodes to edges etc.

What I can't figure out is what do you call or what is this method named, because I can't seem to find a tutorial online and anywhere yet they're existing on some website as a functionality. I want to learn more about this but first I need to know what ***keywords*** I should look for to get all of the information I might need online.

Comment: This is a very ambitious project; rewarding but also quite hard to stem on your own. I don't believe any of your keywords are really going to help you, nor is this a good fit for SO. 'floorplan', 2D, 3D, 'projection' come to mind, but I really wouldn't know where to start, except looking for a library..

Comment: same thoughts exactly but unfortunately no quite luck in Unity game development nor in Unreal side. that's why I'm here I want to dissect this project as little as possible